# What is the best approach to implement a versioning feature with content comparison using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a JSF based web application with backing beans and Hibernate for persistence.

The goal is to implement a feature to compare changes across versions, where some attributes are from "foreign key" objects. In order to get a generic solution, the best way would be to create a kind of database trigger or something.

I know about the `@Version` annotation, but I don't want only to have a history about the persisted object, but also the associated object.

Anyone already done something like that?

Edit: To specify the question here is more detail information. The application have a lot of business objects, most of them just have simple text attributes like Strings. The main thing the application do is CRUD. I would like to build a feature where users can compare versions older versions of a business object. My first idea was just to have a version column in the tables of the business objects and to save always a new dataset with a new version. But this seems for me like a large overload, to save everything duplicated. And how to keep the associations between versioned objects? Is there an other, lighter aprroach for that? This approach would also imply to change every single database access class and save method.

Comment: Your question is too broad - There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I understand, look at my edit, hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what I'm looking for. Event though I wanted to solve it with db triggers, hibernate provides a pretty solution. [Hibernate envers](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs) creates an audit table for each versioned/annotated entity. All you have to do is to set the annotations in auditable entities. The needed tables will be generated and also the history of related audited entities will be managed. So you can recreate the whole content of your entities.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve the problem like this:

- business object table, example: `EXAMPLE_TABLE`

  ```
  -----------------------------------
  |ID         |column 1|column 2|...|
  |----------------------------------
  |1          |foo     |bar     |...|
  |2          |baz     |test    |...|
  |...        |...     |...     |...|
  -----------------------------------
  ```
- history preservation table for each business object table, example: `EXAMPLE_TABLE_HISTORY`

  ```
  ------------------------------------------------
  |ID         |column 1|column 2|...|version|date|
  |-----------------------------------------------
  |1          |null    |foo     |...|1      |    |
  |1          |baz     |test    |...|2      |    |
  |...        |...     |...     |...|...    |... |
  ------------------------------------------------
  ```

You can define database-triggers for `EXAMPLE_TABLE` on each operation (INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE) to copy the current data from `EXAMPLE_TABLE` to `EXAMPLE_TABLE_HISTORY` including a version (Column `version`) and a timestamp (Column `date`) to preserve a history.

Advantages:

- You can easily retrieve all versions of your business object using the `ID` column in the history preservation table.
- Using triggers you don't have to change your application-code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think that's what I am looking for. It's good to solve it in the database. But there is one more thing, how to achieve to hold the relations between business objects in the history table?

Would it be possible to keep relations in the history tables between particular versions of objects?

Like: History_Table(ID, column1, column2, .., version, date, foreign_key, foreign_key_version)

Or am i missnig something?
History_Table(ID, column1, column2, .., version, date, foreign_key <-refers to version in other history table)

Comment: Summarized: Can I handle with triggers relations between objects in history tables?

Comment: You can use the primary key of the business object in `EXAMPLE_TABLE` to retrieve ALL versions of the business object in the history preservation table `EXAMPLE_TABLE_HISTORY` (you can sort the result using the version/date column) or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean something else. Let's say we have the tables car and motor with a 1:1 relationship. Table car has motorId as foreign key. Every version of the car can be dependent on a different motor or on the same motor but in a different version. So the problem is, in the history table every entry have to know which version of the foreign key object is the right one. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You could use the date column to select your data from different tables for a special point in time.

Comment: No, how do you mean this could work? This would end in a mess. I'll test some variations and post my final solution.

Comment: I think I found what I'm looking for. Event though I wanted to solve it with db triggers, hibernate provides a pretty solution. It does what you suggested. Creates an audit table for each versioned/annotated entity. All you have to do ist to set the annotations. I will test it and provide an complete answer. Hibernate Envers Auditing http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/